# Cant get Tomcat running on a Google GCP instance

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, tomcat8

I have launched a google GCP tomcat instance from the standard Tomcat ( Google click to deploy ) image
This uses Debian 9 as the OS.
I am trying to do a basic test on my browser pointing to IP.ADDRESS:8080 but it times out. 
Server.xml in /etc/tomcat8 tells me that tomcat is running on port 8080

The status of tomcat service is as follows

```
    tomcat1@generator1-vm:/etc/tomcat8$ sudo service tomcat8 status
    ● tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
    Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-05-21 13:34:38 UTC; 1h 7min ago
    Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 29722 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 29764 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/tomcat8 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 16 (limit: 4915)
    CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat8.service
    └─848 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/va
    May 21 13:34:33 generator1-vm systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
    May 21 13:34:38 generator1-vm tomcat8[29764]: Starting Tomcat servlet engine: tomcat8.
        May 21 13:34:38 generator1-vm systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Tomcat..
    lines 1-13/13 (END)
```

So this seems to imply that the service is indeed running but I get a service timeout when I try to browse to IP.ADDRESS:8080
Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Odds are it's the GCP firewall.  When you create a Compute Engine instance (which is what you did when you deployed your Tomcat server), you have the option to enable HTTP and/or HTTPS, which will create those firewall rules for you.  But GCP won't automatically create a rule for port 8080, even though Tomcat may be using it.  That is probably why your client is timing out.

Unless you want to open port 8080 for all your virtual machines, the best thing to do is to create a network tag on the virtual machine, and then create a firewall rule that allows traffic from port 8080 to travel to any VM that has that network tag.  First, edit your virtual machine.  You can do that from the web console by clicking the hamburger menu at the top left of the screen and in the COMPUTE" section choose "Compute Engine" and then "VM instances".  Click your VM's name, and when the details page comes up click "EDIT" at the top of the screen. Scroll down until you see the "Network tags" box, and then enter whatever tag you'd like to use.  I suggest something like "port8080".  Then click the blue "Save" button at the bottom of the screen.

Click the hamburger menu again, and this time from the "NETWORKING" section choose "VPC network" and then "Firewall rules".  Click "CREATE FIREWALL RULE" at the top of the screen. Give it whatever name you'd like.  In the "Network" dropdown choose your network, which if you haven't created any custom VPC's should just be "default".  You can leave the priority as it is.  Select "Ingress" for the direction and "Allow" for the action.  For "Targets", select "Specified target tags", and for the "Target tags" enter the tag you created above ("port8080", or whatever you chose to call it).  For "Source filter" select "IP ranges", and for "Source IP ranges" enter 0.0.0.0/0 (which is shorthand for "everyone").  Skip the "Second source filter".  For "Protocols and ports" choose "Specified protocols and ports", and in the box below enter "tcp:8080".  Then click the "Create" button and you should be good to go.